# couchDB design doc is not at the end of all other docs

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I have a couchDB database with a single design doc in it. For some reason the design doc is not at the end of all my other records/docs. This is causing a problem as i usually query for _all_docs and then remove the last result (which should be the design doc)

This is also a problem when using endkey='_' to not return the design doc.

Another anomaly i noticed is after deleting the design doc all together and querying with endkey='_' it ends the results half way through. And the record it ends at is also funny enough where the design doc was sitting before deleting it.

Any ideas???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption that a design doc is always the last row of a view result is wrong.

All views are sorted by their key, and _all_docs is a view, which uses doc._id as the key.

Your code was probably working in the past just by coincidence. Presumably you were having only docs with IDs starting with numbers in the past, and now there are docs that have IDs with letters at the beginning. (The underscore as in "_design/foo" comes alphabetically after digits and before the letter "a".)

Comment: I wish it was that simple! All my ID's are auto generated by couchDB so they are all numbers or letters. This is a test DB there are only about 10 records. They all start with a number or letter and there is one single design doc. One of these docs is messed up for some reason. Thats why after deleting the design doc and querying with endkey=_ it only returns the first 4 of 10 docs. Even though again ALL of their ID's have no '_' in them.

Comment: If you query _all_docs without a start- and endkey, it will show you all documents in the database. I guess that 6 docs have an ID starting with a letter. That would explain, why you only see 4 docs - all having an ID starting with a number - when you use an underscore ("_") for the endkey.

Comment: Ohhh are underscores ranked higher than a number in the couchDB ordering scheme?